# SQLalchemy - Session and multiple databases attempt to create indexes twice

Tags: python, sqlite, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLalchemy with automap and a series of SQLite databases produced by a program I have no control over. I need however to extend the databases to provide additional functionality, so I use the SQLalchemy ORM to modify this database and use automap to access the tables and columns that I did not change.

Classes definition (which stays in its own module):

```
Base = automap_base()

class VariantAssociation(Base):

    __tablename__ = "sample_variant_association"

    vid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("variants.variant_id"),
                 primary_key=True, index=True)
    sid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("samples.sample_id"),
                 primary_key=True, index=True)

    vdepth = Column(Integer, index=True)
    valt_depth = Column(Integer, index=True)
    gt = Column(Text)
    gt_type = Column(Integer)
    fraction = Column(Float, index=True)

    variant = relationship("Variant", back_populates="samples")
    sample = relationship("Samples", back_populates="variants")


class Variant(Base):

    __tablename__ = "variants"

    variant_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    info = deferred(Column(LargeBinary))

    samples = relationship("VariantAssociation",
                           back_populates="variant")

    compressed = False

    _gt_alt_depths = None
    _gt_depths = None
    _gts = None
    _gt_types = None

    def decompress(self, compressed=False):

        if compressed:
            unpack = snappy_unpack_blob
        else:
            unpack = unpack_blob

        self._gt_alt_depths = unpack(self.gt_alt_depths)
        self._gt_depths = unpack(self.gt_depths)
        self._gts = unpack(self.gts)
        self._gt_types = unpack(self.gt_types)


    def __repr__(self):

        data = "<Variant {chrom}:{start}-{end} {gene} {ref}/{alt} {type}>"

        return data.format(chrom=self.chrom,
                           start=self.start,
                           end=self.end,
                           gene=self.gene,
                           ref=self.ref,
                           alt=self.alt,
                           type=self.type)

    @property
    def alt_depths(self):
        return self._gt_alt_depths

    @property
    def depths(self):
        return self._gt_depths

    @property
    def genotypes(self):
        return self._gts

    @property
    def genotype_types(self):
        return self._gt_types


class Samples(Base):

    __tablename__ = "samples"

    sample_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(Text, index=True)
    variants = relationship("VariantAssociation",
                            back_populates="sample")


class DataMigration(Base):

    __tablename__ = "datamigration"
    done = Column(Boolean, primary_key=True)
```

I then load the database with this approach (in a different function, which imports `Base` from where the tables are defined):

```
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///{}".format(database),
                           poolclass=StaticPool,
                           echo=echo)

# Create association table if not present
VariantAssociation.__table__.create(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)
DataMigration.__table__.create(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)

Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
```

However, if I load two databases, whatever happens with the first leaks into the subsequent runs:

```
db = load_database("file1.db") # All right
db2 = load_database("file2.db") # Throws exception
```

The exception in question is:

```
io.py in load_database(database)
150 
151     # Create association table if not present
--> 152     VariantAssociation.__table__.create(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)
153     DataMigration.__table__.create(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)
154 
[cut exception all into SQLalchemy internals]
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) index ix_sample_variant_association_valt_depth already exists [SQL: 'CREATE INDEX ix_sample_variant_association_valt_depth ON sample_variant_association (valt_depth)']
```

It doesn't occur if I load the database in a separate session, so somehow the state of `db` is leaking into `db2`.

What's the best way to ensure that each loaded database ORM is independent?

EDIT: more debugging shows that `CREATE INDEX` is used twice:

```
2017-09-15 15:18:00,284 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2017-09-15 15:18:00,417 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2017-09-15 15:18:00,418 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine CREATE INDEX 
ix_sample_variant_association_valt_depth ON sample_variant_association 
(valt_depth)
2017-09-15 15:18:00,418 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2017-09-15 15:18:00,550 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2017-09-15 15:18:00,551 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine CREATE INDEX 
ix_sample_variant_association_valt_depth ON sample_variant_association 
(valt_depth)
```

Comment: If you are trying to reflect two separate databases, then you need to create two separate `Base`s with two separate `MetaData`.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know in advance. I have usually just one file, but sometimes more than one and I need to load them all at once. I understand I'm likely misusing the ORM here.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you don't know it in advance. You can create them dynamically. Do the databases have the same schema? Perhaps you can provide some background on *why* you need to load multiple databases at runtime?

Comment: @Einar, were you able to fix this problem? If so, can you share the solution. I'm running into a similar problem.

Comment: I have an idea but I never implemented it: trying to create the schema dynamically and not statically.